# Mongo DB Document only returns with "_id" that has "$oid"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying a very simple CRUD API with the MEAN stack. I entered several documents into a mongolab sandbox db. I could do a GET on all documents and they would all be returned. Then I tested GET by ID:

```
router.route('/api/v1/resources/:resource_id')

// get the resource with that id (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/resources/:resource_id)
.get(function(req, res) {
    Resource.findById(req.params.resource_id, function(err, resources) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(resources);
    });
});
```

And it simply wouldn't work. I kept getting null. But the document existed. I could see it when I would do a GET on all documents.

Then I got another document to return, finally.

The difference? The record that returned had an id in this format:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid":"1234567890abc"}
}
```

But records that did not return had this:

```
{
   "_id": "1234567890abc"
}
```

Can Anyone explain this to me? I entered the data with Postman and I didn't do anything different between the entries.

What is $oid?
What creates the $oid?
Why does that nesting matter for mongoose's findById()?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah the `_id` thing with mongodb was a bit confusing at first for me. the 'standard' way is an _id that is of type ObjectId. but then Meteor will simply use strings outright instead of ObjectId, or something like that. now i see this $oid stuff too. the good news: you're welcome to explicitly set the value of the _id yourself (if you're using the raw mongo native node.js driver, at least)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. What's the raw mongo native node.js driver? Do you mean, I could set it myself? Like to 1, 2, 3, 4? (Perhaps not the most sophisticated thing to do but just asking.)

Comment: yes, with this one: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Answer (score 8):

`$oid` is from [Strict MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#oid).

All your queries to MongoDB database that contains `_id` conditions should wrap `_id` in `ObjectId` function like the following:

```
db.resources.findOne({_id: ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0013")};
```

MongoLab provides UI for querying to MongoDB via JSON syntax. But you can't use `ObjectId` in JSON due specification restrictions.

So, MongoLab uses *Strict MongoDB Extended JSON* for alias `ObjectId()` -> `$oid`.

```
{"_id": {"$oid":"507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"})
```

Same `$oid` you see in the output because MongoLab UI uses JSON also.

Mongoose automatically converts a string `_id` to MongoDB query so you don't need doing it manually. The following queries are equivalent:

```
Resource.findById("507c35dd8fada716c89d0013");
Resource.findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Artem. I'm still a little lost with it but I appreciate it. So, the thing I did was, I went into my mongolab sandbox and manually changed _id's to have _id: { $oid: "###########" } if they did not. After I did that - Resource.findById(req.params.resource_id, function(err, resources) { - worked fine. Perhaps that solution is as elegant as a bag of hammers but it worked.

Comment: How do you save your documents in MongoDB?

Comment: I entered my documents through Postman, the chrome app. When I modified them I just went in and edited right on mongolab.

Comment: Unfortunately I did't work with Postman. In mongoose you don't need find about id because it always guarantees id's in correct format